# Ordering by field combined

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have this set of rules to sort my results in both MySQL & sql-server:

1. First sort by `qty` - from highest to lowest
2. Above sorted result sort again by `storage`, and first put 2, than
   values >2, than <2
3. Above sorted result sort once again by `price` - from lowest to
   highest

I wrote followig clauses:

1. `ORDER BY table.qty DESC`
2. `ORDER BY FIELD (table.storage, =2, >2, <2)`
3. `ORDER BY table.price ASC`

Combining means for me that from data:

```
qty,storage,price
0,0,0
1,1,10
1,2,22
1,3,10
2,3,10
1,2,9
```

I would get:

```
qty,storage,price
2,3,10
1,2,9
1,2,22
1,1,10
1,3,10
0,0,0
```

I need help with two things:

## 1 - 2nd clause returns error and I suppose its because wrong use of operators:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '>2,<2)

## 2 - how to chain those clauses together

I have no idea how to do it really, but let following pseudo-queryilustrate it:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
ORDER BY
    table.qty DESC
AND
    ORDER BY FIELD (
        table.storage, =2, >2, <2
    )
AND
    ORDER BY
        table.price ASC
```

Comment: For me it's obvious what 'chaining' means, but don't hesitate to ask for details if it's not clear for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MSSQLServer you could use

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
ORDER BY
    table.qty DESC,
    CASE
        WHEN table.storage = 2 THEN 1
        WHEN table.storage > 2 THEN 2
        WHEN table.storage < 2 THEN 3
    END ASC,
    table.price ASC
```

[CASE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CASE_TSQL%29;k%28SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1%29;k%28SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1%29;k%28MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT%29;k%28DevLang-TSQL%29&rd=true)

Comment: It's fine for me! Could you explain/direct me to some resources about what `THEN x` does?

Comment: @Ultra, added the reference.